# TeXShop KeyBinding file location

Tags: texshop

Does anyone know the current TeXShop KeyBinding file location?

It used to be stored in DefaultKeyBinding.dict file. I searched the entire disk of my new mac with the newest TexShop 5.25 installed and this file is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file that is a general keybinding file for all apps that use Apple's Text Framework (e.g., TeXShop, Mail). Note: ~/Library is the Library folder in your Home folder NOT `/Library` in the root of your HD/SSD and the KeyBindings folder and DefaultKeyBinding.dict file don't exist by default.

In addition, TeXShop has its own Key Bindings under the Source Menu. That has a toggle to turn it on or off as well as an Editor to add/change/delete keybindings. The file for that is `~/Library/TeXShop/Keyboard/autocompletion.plist` although you just use the Key Binding Editor to change it. Those key bindings can be used only for single press (possibly multiple key) keys not for keys that require two strokes to complete: e.g., Shift-Opt-8 is OK but to get é on a US keyboard you first press Opt-e and then (a separate keystroke) e which isn't allowed in TeXShop's Key Bindings.